# Find my error? Integral involving $e^{-t}$

Tags: calculus

I'd appreciate it if someone could look over my integration.
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} e^{-t}\cdot (1+e^{-t})^{-2}dt$$
$$=(1+e^{-x})^{-1}-\lim_{s\rightarrow-\infty}(1+e^{-s})^{-1}$$
by a $u$-substitution. The right term is 1 by L'Hopital's rule. So my final answer is:
$$=(1+e^{-x})^{-1}-1$$

Any comments much appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: the right term is not 1 but 0. The answer should then be:
$$=(1+e^{-x})^{-1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is the right term $1$? Shouldn't it be $0$?

We have

$$\lim_{s \rightarrow -\infty} (1+e^{-s})^{-1} = \lim_{s \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{1}{1+e^{-s}} = 0 $$

Comment: Well, I rewrote the rational expression first: $\frac{e^s}{1+e^s}$. Then, indeterminate form (0/0) and L'Hopital says to take derivates of num and dem which is 1.

Comment: But I clearly see that the limit is 0 now. Yikes!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Though just to make sure, what you have written isn't an indeterminate form... it's $0/1$! ;)

Comment: L'Hopital is rolling in his grave. Merci.